# HtmlAgilityPack get data from strong tag

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

```
<strong
data-price-without-addons="&#x20AC;&nbsp;12"
data-price-with-parking=""
data-price-with-internet=""
data-price-with-internet-parking=""
data-component='track' data-track='mouseenter' data-hash='eDUfZZGbBVfXWMHBYWEISLJYbcNKNMC' data-stage='1'
class=" b-tooltip-with-price-breakdown-tracker rooms-table-room-price red-actual-rack-rate"
title=""
>
&#x20AC;&nbsp;12
</strong>
```

Hello everybody, this code is on webbrowser1.
I want get '€ 12.

I try this, but this is not working;

```
var element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("strong")
 .Cast<HtmlElement>()
 .Where(ee => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ee.GetAttribute("class")) &&
 ee.GetAttribute("class") == " b-tooltip-with-price-breakdown-tracker")
 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Someone help me ?

Thanks, Jimmy Puaa Kuaa.

Comment: What type is `webBrowser1`? Are you really using HtmlAgilityPack or just .NET standard browser control? What's the problem with your current codes?

Comment: So what you want is to get the innerText from your Strong tag ?